# Remove decimals from a product attribute and add suffix to its value

Tags: php, product-attribute

i copy `weight` attribute value to another product attribute named `general_weight` by this php code:

```
<?php
require_once  "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app("admin");
umask();

/*
 Step2: get Product Collection filter by Saleable
*/
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('weight');

foreach($collection as $product){
$val=$product->getWeight();
/*$product->getWeight() is not given the value then used 

$product->getResource()->getAttribute('weight')->getFrontend()->getValue($product-)

*/
$product->setGeneralWeight($val);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'general_weight');

}
```

my `weight` attribute has for decimals like: `90.0000` . i want to remove those decimals from `general_weight` attribute and add a suffix to it like (`KG`).
at the end i want `90.0000` from `weight` attribute to be copied to `general_weight` attribute this way: `90 KG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your `weight` attribute is type of string:

```
$val = preg_replace('/\..*$/', 'KG', $product->getWeight());
```

or in case of float:

```
$val = floor($product->getWeight()) . 'KG';
```

Comment: May i know, which location i need to edit....

Comment: The location you output the weight.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the values are float ending in '.0000' then try

```
$general_weight = $product->getWeight() * 1 . 'kg';
```

Comment: Sorry for being picky but this can produce something like `1.5kg` in case `weight` attribute is stored as float while initial requirement was to drop decimal part.

Comment: could you pls guide me by default, where i can change in my Magento file.